# Why can I modify ListView in javafx from a thread other than JavaFx Apllication Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am quite new to java and javafx. While Learning javafx I learnt that if a thread other than Javafx Application Thread tries to modify UI then IllegalStateException will be thrown
But I am being able to modify a listview from another thread, how is this working?

My UI contains a button and listview, here is the event handler for button:

```
@FXML
private void Start(){
    ObservableList<String> lst = FXCollections.observableArrayList("abc","kjadkjas");
    new Thread(() -> {
        listView.setItems(lst);
    }).start();
}
```

I tried googling quite a lot, but found nothing of this sort

Comment: the threading rule rules always - even if violating it doesn't seem to have any _immediate_ bad consequences (not every potential change is guarded against it), simply don't the code is brittle and might fail any time.

Comment: Note that one reason you may be able to do this is if the `ListView` is not currently in a `Scene` that is attached to a window. From the [`Node` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html): *"Node objects may be constructed and modified on any thread as long they are not yet attached to a Scene in a Window that is showing."*. However, there's pretty much never any reason to do this, so I would recommend avoiding it. To emphasize, though, breaking the threading rules might cause your program to fail, even if no immediate exception is thrown.

Comment: @James_D how come it is not part of a scene at the time the thread executes?, listview is in the UI and the thread starts upon the button press

Comment: In that case, it will be part of the scene - but there's no way anyone can know that from the code you posted (or anything else in the question). I was just pointing out one possible way that an exception might not be thrown. But if the `ListView` is part of the scene, you **must not** modify it from a background thread.

Comment: (I butchered my first attempt at that last comment, but it is correct now.)

Comment: "_I learnt that if a thread other than Javafx Application Thread tries to modify UI then IllegalStateException will be thrown_" – the takeaway here should be that what you learned is not entirely correct. Only some operations actively check if they're invoked on the FX thread, throwing an ISE if not. Other operations do not actively check and thus allow the background thread to make changes—but that does not mean the code is not broken. Sharing mutable state between threads (e.g. background thread & FX thread) without proper synchronization can lead to _undefined behavior_.